# can't connect to postgres using jdbc driver in a ManagedBean

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, jdbc, primefaces

I work on a java web application using jsf and Primefaces, with Glassfish 4.1.1 as my application server and PostgreSQL as my database.
I have a form containing a selectOneMenu which value is sent to the ManagedBean with a commandButton.
The ManagedBean then try to connect to the database using the DriverManager and execute a query which results are displayed in a panelGrid.

This is the java code in the ManagedBean Pays.java :

```
public void save() throws NamingException, SQLException{ 

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/zones_franches?user=postgres&password=jihane";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM pays WHERE id_geom = "+ idGeom +";");
        System.out.println("Query executed....");

        if(rs.next()) {
            idPays = rs.getString("id_pays");
            nom = rs.getString("nom");
            superficie = rs.getString("superficie");
            pib2014 = rs.getString("pib_2014");
            population2014 = rs.getString("population_2014");
            inflation = rs.getString("inflation");
            investissements = rs.getString("investissements");
            indDoingBus = rs.getInt("ind_doing_business");

            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        }else{
            System.out.print("try again !");
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        }
}
```

And this is the xhtml page code :

```
<h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputLabel for="pays" value="Pays sélectionné : " />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="pays" value="#{pays.idGeom}" required="true" label="ID Pays">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Egypte" itemValue="1" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton process="@parent:@parent" update="@form" value="Détails" action="#{pays.save()}"/>
                    <br/>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/misc/kobe.png" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <h:outputText value="Code Pays :" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{pays.idGeom}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Id Pays :" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{pays.idPays}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Nom Pays :" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{pays.nom}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

The problem is that the results are not displayed in the panelGrid, even if the save() method is executed when I click on the commandButton.

Comment: If you add a big `try { ... } catch (Exception e} { ... }` around the code within the `save()` function, and log any such thrown exceptions, what do you see?  I suspect that some exception is happening, and that that exception would help provide data on the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Did you read the server log for clues?

Comment: I tried the `try{...} catch (Exception e)` and I found this exception on the server log : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/zones_franches?user=postgres&password=jihane
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
 at Pays.save(Pays.java:46)

Comment: should I download and install a nex driver? I found this driver whithin the drivers available on databases service (I work with NetBeans) and I succefully executed a command with it, but in the `save()`function it doesn't work..